# Pass multiple types as parameter in filter function of Iterable object in Xtend

Tags: xtext, iterable, xtend

I am using the DSL generator interface of Xtext in order to generate some models based on my Xtext DSL. This is working fine, but right now I am facing a bit of a problem in writing the generator. I am using the generator to filter out Rules declared in my Xtext DSL. I do this by selecting certain Rules and then convert them in an `Iterable` object, which I can then use to filter on certain types (see the `toIterable.filter()` parts in my code below). The code below contains one for loop which itself again contains 3 nested for loops. These nested loops all filter on one specific kind of Method Statement (types that I declared in my DSL). I would like to combine these 3 for loops in one for loop by passing the 3 types as parameters in the `filter()` method. In this case there would be one nested for loop where the condition would ideally look something like:

```
for (eachMethodStatement : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(StatementSort1, StatementSort2, StatementSort3)
```

The problem is that the `filter()` method only takes one argument (one type), so right now I have to write three dispatch methods called `getDemand` which all basically do the same. It works right now, but this forces me to write a lot of boilerplate code for each type that I want to filter.

Is there a way to filter multiple types (in one for loop) without creating a lot of boilerplate code?

```
for (ifStatement : ifElseStatement.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(IfStatements)){
    for (persistenceFunction : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(SingleLibraryPersistenceMethodStatement)) {
            expressionDemand += getDemand(persistenceFunction,resourceTable)                            
        }
    for (interfaceFunction : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(SingleLibraryInterFaceMethodStatement)) {                    
            expressionDemand += getDemand(interfaceFunction,resourceTable)                          
        }
    for (businessFunction : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(SingleLibraryBusinessMethodStatement)) {                  
            expressionDemand += getDemand(businessFunction,resourceTable)
        }
    for (persistenceFunction : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(RelationalOperator)) {
            expressionDemand += getDemand(persistenceFunction,resourceTable)                            
        }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason not to iterate over all contents and check the type to add with an if instanceof?

Comment: alternatively you can use the filter method that takes a predicate and do the instanceof there

Comment: Christian thanks for your answer. This is also definitely an option, so I will try that out and also try out the switch statement as described below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<T> T filter(Class<T>)` cannot do multiple types because then the return type could not be `T` but - in the extreme case `Object` which must be cast later.

But: If your *four* types (`SingleLibraryPersistenceMethodStatement`, `SingleLibraryInterFaceMethodStatement`, `SingleLibraryBusinessMethodStatement`, `RelationalOperator`) share a specific interface or supertype you can used that with the existing `filter()` method:

```
for (ifStatement : ifElseStatement.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(IfStatements)){
    for (statement : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(Statement)) {
            expressionDemand += getDemand(statement,resourceTable)                          
    }
}
def Demand getDemand(Statement statement, ResourceTable resourceTable){
    ...
}
```

Another solution is to avoid `filter` in this case and use `switch` with type guards like this:

```
for (ifStatement : ifElseStatement.eAllContents.toIterable.filter(IfStatements)){
    for (it : ifStatement.expression.eAllContents) {
        switch(it){
            SingleLibraryPersistenceMethodStatement,
            SingleLibraryPersistenceMethodStatement,
            SingleLibraryBusinessMethodStatement:
                 expressionDemand += getDemand(it,resourceTable)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A.H. I also considered the first option, but that would involve quite rigorously changing my DSL declared in xText (not something impossible, but quite a hassle for fixing a relatively small problem). I tried declaring a supertype in my DSL, but that worked more as an abstract class instead of an interface (bit hard to explain, but the generator did not function as required anymore). The second option is definitely something I am going to try; simple and elegant enought for my case (although better structured probably exist, but that would also require way more refactoring effort).